# Integrating two keras models into one model

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, keras

I have three models (Model - identifying objects in an image, Model B - identifying style of an image, Model C - identifying keywords from an image) trained using Keras - having three different model architectures - used to classify an image into three different ways.

I have a server which wraps around these models to serve up the predictions of on the fly based on request i.e. user uploads an image and chooses between identifying objects, style or keywords. I only have 1 GPU. Because of the way Keras allocates GPU memory, I have wrapped the prediction models in functions. This way after each function call the memory is released.

This works as long as there is one request for the same model. But if two requests (say one for style and other for keywords) - hits the server - Keras runs out of memory and goes into an irrecoverable loop. I have to then kill the process and restart the server to get it working again.

I had a few ideas on how to solve the problem. Not sure which are feasible and will work though.

1. Get 2 more GPU instances and create a 1:1 mapping from server to
   model to GPU.
2. Create a single model from the trained models. Can someone confirm if this is possible? And if yes, how?
3. Create a virtualisation layer over the GPU and access GPU through it. Can someone confirm if this is possible? And if yes, how?